# How to add an AWS EC2 Security Group ingress rule for *my* host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address

The EC2 web console can do this with interactive use, when adding an ingress rule to a Security Group, under `EC2 >> Security Groups >> Edit >> Custom >> MyIP` using the same IP I logged in with.  I want to do this in a programmed way but I see nothing in the EC2 API for this.  I am using Python 2.7 with botocore 1.4.36 for this programming.  How can I accomplish the same thing in a programmed way (user will download and run a big script which needs to add or verify this SG rule so it can log in to an instance it launches or finds) without querying whatismyip?

Comment: Heyo, check out boto3. http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#securitygroup and you can get the IP with a request to an external service like whatismyip

Comment: i regularly query that service, or others like it, to verify my VPN is properly active.  i have, at times, found them to be down (though not all at once).